# Rails - nesting includes with where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model:

**Item**

```
has_many :sizes
has_many :prices, through: sizes
```

What I want to do is to load everything (sizes and prices) while loading Items, so:

```
@items = Item.includes(sizes: [:prices])
```

What I also want to do is to load only prices that has `currency` set to `EUR`.

How can I do that? Is there a way to somehow put `.where()` condition into this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Item.includes(sizes: :prices).where({ prices: { currency: 'EUR' } })
```

Comment: Easier that I thought it would be! Thanks for saving me time writing those SQL queries!